# Find an example where a subset of “inverse fixed points“ is not a subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a group of odd order, $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $G$, and $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}$.

I want to find an example to show that
$G_s= \{ g \in G \mid \sigma \left( g \right)= g^{-1} \} $ might not be a subgroup of $G$.

$G$ has to be a non-Abelian group.
If $G_s$ is a group, it should be an Abelian group.
I tried some examples (the orders of most examples are not very large), but I didn't find counterexamples.

Comment: $G$ non-abelian of order 6 with derived subgroup $C_3$, $\sigma$ conjugation by an element $t$ of order $2$. Then $G_\sigma$ is $C_3\cup\{t\}$ which is not a subgroup. ($G_s$ is a bad notation: it should refer to $\sigma$)

Comment: @YCor, the OP did say odd order.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg ok, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For an odd prime $p$, let  $$G = \langle a,b \mid a^p=b^p=[[a,b],a]=[[a,b],b]=1 \rangle$$ be an extraspecial group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$.

Then there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $G$ with $\sigma^2=1$, $\sigma(a)=a^{-1}$, $\sigma(b)=b^{-1}$, and $\sigma([a,b])=[a,b]$.

Since $a,b \in G_s$ but $G_s \ne G$,  it is clear that $G_s$ cannot be a subgroup of $G$. In fact $|G_s| = p^2$.

Comment: In terms of Lie algebras: if $p$ is an odd prime and $L$ is a Lie algebra over $\mathbf{F}_p$ of nilpotency class $<p$, an automorphism of order $2$ is the same as a grading $L=L_0\oplus L_1$ in $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, and one is thus considering $L_1$. The question is then to have an example with $L_1$ not a Lie subalgebra. This is indeed the case with $L$ Heisenberg with basis $(x,y,z)$, $[x,y]=z$, $x,y$ of degree $1$ and $z$ of degree $0$. This is exactly the example described here.

Comment: By the way, this also shows, if $G$ is a $p$-group of nilpotency class $<p$ and $\sigma$ is an arbitrary automorphism, that $\{g:\sigma(g)=g^{-1}\}$ has cardinal a power of $p$ (although not necessarily a subgroup). I don't know what happens for arbitrary $p$-groups, even for involutive automorphisms.